# How to bind multiple properties to [HttpGet] with out using any model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to bind multiple properties to [HTTPGet] with out using any model class?
It's an API call and we are not using any form or JQuery.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult PreventiveMaintance(Employee emp)
    {
        //Logic
        return Ok();
    }
```

I have Employee class with properties like FirstName, LastName, DateOfJoining.
Going forward there is a great chance in increasing number of properties in the Employee class. But we want that to be dynamic, so that whenever there is any change in business, we don't want to Modify the Employee class. Can we achieve it without any model or viewmodel concept.

Sample code will be much appreciated.. :)

Thanks

Comment: Why should an entire `Employee` object be provided. The method name suggests something that could do with just an ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Although C# is a statically typed language, from C# 4.0 you can use the `dynamic` type to bypass static type checking, so you could try the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult PreventiveMaintance(dynamic emp)
{
    //Logic
    return Ok();
}
```

Note that by using this type you will get a run-time exception if the member you are trying to access does not exist, here is more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Alternatively you could develop your API using a dynamically typed language like Python and a framework such as Flask or Django (e.g. https://pythonbasics.org/flask-rest-api).